# Why is SymmetricDS taking so long to sync?

Tags: symmetricds

When running SymmetricDS on system which has an unreliable connection, it takes a long time for sync to catch up when the connection comes back.

What kind of configuration values can I look at to make that sync goes faster?

Answer (score 1):

There's no one definite answer. Configuration of symmetricDs parameters is a tradeoff. Improving one thing could harm another. Spend some time reading about different parameters, measuring and then trying what improves the performance or... be patient.